# How to change the visibility of a button in windows phone 8 dynamically

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, datatemplate, code-behind

I have ListBox with two text blocks and one button. By default the button's visibilty is collapsed.

**ListBox**

```
 <ListBox x:Name="companiesList" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ContentPanel}"  SelectionChanged="companiesList_SelectionChanged" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="listItem" Background="{Binding BackgroundBrush}">

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <StackPanel x:Name="namePanel" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="50">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="nameTextBlock" Text="{Binding CompanyName}" Foreground="#FF501F6E" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="28" MaxHeight="50" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="460" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Fonts/Riwaj.ttf#Riwaj"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel x:Name="addressPanel" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,-5,0,5" Height="35">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="addressTextBlock"  Text="{Binding Address}" Foreground="#FF1F1F1F" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20" MaxHeight="35" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="460" FontFamily="Fonts/Riwaj.ttf#Riwaj"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel x:Name="phonePanel" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="35">
                            <Button x:Name="sponseredButton" Style ="{StaticResource ButtonStyleIB}"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="spon_button_clicked" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <Image x:Name="sponseredButtonImage" Source="{Binding SponseredImageSource}" Stretch="None" />
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <Image  x:Name="line" Grid.Row="3" Width="460" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/separator.png"  />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

**Now in my code behind file(.cs file) I want to change the visibility of  button based on the some condition.**

Please help me how to do that.

Comment: :you have to use visual tree concept ....it wll work for you

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this with setting the `Visibility` property of the button to `Collapsed` in the `XAML` and when your specific condition in the CS code meets set the `Visibility` of the button to `Visible.

In the .cs code behind the XAML add this snippet:

```
sponseredButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have use visul tree for findind list box item

[How to access a Control placed inside ListBox ItemTemplate in WP7](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-access-a-control-placed-inside-listbox-itemtemplate-in-wp7)

if any query than let me know

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need to achieve that is a Converter. Lets assume that you want the button to be visible only for specific sponsors:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="phonePanel" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="35">
    <Button x:Name="sponseredButton" Style ="{StaticResource ButtonStyleIB}"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="spon_button_clicked" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Visibility="{Binding SponseredName Converter={StaticResource SponsorConverter}}">
        <Image x:Name="sponseredButtonImage" Source="{Binding SponseredImageSource}" Stretch="None" />
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

And the converter as follows:

```
public class SponsorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Assuming that you have the sponsor's name as string as follows: 
        var sn = SponseredName.ToString();

        if (sn.Equals("A"))
           return Visibility.Visible;
        elseif () ...

        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to define you converter in the XAML file that you will be using it.

Find more about Converters [here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Collection_of_Value_converters_for_Windows_Phone_apps).